# How to wrap functools.cache in another decorator?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a wrapper for `functools.cache` so that it only triggers if `self.use_cache` is true.

I'm having a lot of trouble getting the syntax right on this. Every time I wrap `lru_cache` or `cache` it treats the wrapped function as a unique instance of the function, and doesn't cache it. Can anyone help guide me on this?

```
import functools

def cache():
    return functools.cache if self.use_cache else lambda x: x

@dataclass
class F5Query():
    use_cache: bool = True

    __hash__(self): 
        return hash(self.use_cache)

    @cache
    def _test_cache(self, input):
        """Return the same number each time if cache is working."""
        from uuid import uuid4
        return uuid4()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```py
import uuid
import functools
import dataclasses

def cache(func):
    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
        new_func = functools.cache(func) if self.use_cache else func
        return new_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
    return inner

@dataclasses.dataclass
class F5Query():
    use_cache: bool = True

    @cache
    def test_cache(self):
        return uuid.uuid4()
        
query = F5Query(use_cache=True)
first = query.test_cache()
assert query.test_cache() == first

query = F5Query(use_cache=False)
first = query.test_cache()
assert query.test_cache() != first
```

Comment: As written, that code generates a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'F5Query'`. I added the following: `def __hash__(self): return hash(self.use_cache)`. 
After that, it still returns: `AssertionError: assert query.test_cache() == first`.

On the bright side, it does seem to be able to get the class attribute this way, so thank you for helping so far!